# cypher 2.0 : using label based index to search a set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `users` and `groups` they belong to.
I have an index n:Group(name)

I want to search for all users belong to a set of groups : ["gr1","gr2","gr3"]

which other groups they belong to.

so I have the following query:
Query :

```
MATCH (gr:Group) <--(us:User)--(gr2:Group)
WHERE gr.name in ["gr1","gr2"]
return distinct gr2
```

The thing here, is that I think that cypher don't use the index because the query is to slow.

I have 2k nodes, 50k relationships. 
The following query takes between 200 to 700 ms (depending on cache):

```
MATCH (gr:Group) <--(us:User)--(gr2:Group)
WHERE gr.name = "gr1"
return distinct gr2
```

However, the following query, takes between 2 to 6 seconds!

```
MATCH (gr:Group) <--(us:User)--(gr2:Group)
WHERE gr.name in ["gr1"]
return distinct gr2
```

When I'm trying to do :

```
MATCH (gr:Group) <--(us:User)--(gr2:Group)
using index gr:Group(name)
WHERE gr.name in ["gr1"]
return distinct gr2
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot use index hint in this context. The label and property comparison must be specified on a non-optional node
Label: `Group`
Property name: `name`
```

(with "=" instead of "in" I get no  error)

I'm using neo4j enterprise 2.0.1 . The test results are from running on the neo4j browser .

Comment: `IN` is not yet supported for index lookups on properties for a label, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

The index is referred either when you specify the attribs in the pattern as in `(gr:Group {name: "gr1"})` or you call `WHERE gr.name = "gr1"`. In your case where multiple attrib values are possible you can use `OR` clause.

```
MATCH (gr:Group) <--(us:User)--(gr2:Group)
WHERE gr.name="gr1" OR gr.name="gr2"
return distinct gr2
```

Comment: I need querying with parameters, meaning I want to pass an array of group names to the query. In neo 1.9, I could at least START from a set of nodes (given by parameter). Is there no way to do that in 2.0? (I can create a string like you've mentioned dynamically by adding more possible values to the or statement, but that is kinda missing the point..)

Comment: Unfortunately that's currently not yet possible. You can use `gr.name IN {names}` but that won't use the index and makes only sense if you only have a few :Group nodes.