# cypher 2.0 : optimize query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Following my former question : 
[cypher 2.0 : using label based index to search a set of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617625/cypher-2-0-using-label-based-index-to-search-a-set-of-nodes)

I am trying to optimize a query to find users common groups:

```
MATCH (gr:Group) <--(us:User)-->(gr2:Group)
WHERE gr.name = "gr1" or gr.name = "gr2" 
return distinct gr2 as prop, count(distinct us ) as users
limit 10
```

Unfortunately, it takes about 4-5 seconds.
Ran 'profile' on the query and got the following result:

```
ColumnFilter(symKeys=["prop", "  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE074636fa-2950-4845-93ae-9d87da36e2b5"], returnItemNames=["prop", "users"], _rows=10, _db_hits=0)
Slice(limit="Literal(10)", _rows=10, _db_hits=0)
  EagerAggregation(keys=["Cached(prop of type Node)"], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATE074636fa-2950-4845-93ae-9d87da36e2b5,Distinct(Count(us),us))"], _rows=10, _db_hits=0)
    Extract(symKeys=["us", "  UNNAMED20", "gr", "gr2", "r"], exprKeys=["prop"], _rows=34060, _db_hits=0)
      Filter(pred="((Property(pr,name(1)) == Literal(gr1) OR Property(pr,name(1)) == Literal(gr2)) AND hasLabel(gr:Group(2)))", _rows=34060, _db_hits=68120)
        SimplePatternMatcher(g="(us)-['  UNNAMED20']-(gr)", _rows=34060, _db_hits=1653118)
          Filter(pred="hasLabel(gr2:Group(2))", _rows=28188, _db_hits=0)
            TraversalMatcher(start={"label": "User", "producer": "NodeByLabel", "identifiers": ["us"]}, trail="(us)-[r WHERE hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():Group(2)) AND true]-(gr2)", _rows=28188, _db_hits=48828)
```

gets up to 1653118 db_hits

However the following query takes only 200 ms:

```
MATCH (gr:Group) <--(us:User)-->(gr2:Group)
WHERE gr.name = "gr1" or gr.name = "gr2" 
return distinct gr2 as prop
limit 10
```

And, its profile :

```
Slice(limit="Literal(10)", _rows=10, _db_hits=0)
Distinct(_rows=10, _db_hits=0)
  Extract(symKeys=["us", "  UNNAMED20", "gr", "gr2", "r"], exprKeys=["prop"], _rows=17, _db_hits=0)
    Filter(pred="((Property(gr,name(1)) == Literal(gr1) OR Property(gr,name(1)) == Literal(gr2)) AND hasLabel(gr:Group(2)))", _rows=17, _db_hits=34)
      SimplePatternMatcher(g="(us)-['  UNNAMED20']-(gr)", _rows=17, _db_hits=600)
        Filter(pred="hasLabel(gr2:Group(2))", _rows=10, _db_hits=0)
          TraversalMatcher(start={"label": "User", "producer": "NodeByLabel", "identifiers": ["us"]}, trail="(us)-[r WHERE hasLabel(NodeIdentifier():Group(2)) AND true]-(gr2)", _rows=10, _db_hits=18)
```

gets only to 600 db_hits at top

Is there any way to change the first query to get the same results in a better performance?
I just can't accept a 4 sec per query performance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is

```
MATCH (gr:Group)
WHERE gr.name = "gr1" or gr.name = "gr2" 
WITH gr
MATCH  (gr)<--(us:User)-->(gr2:Group)
return distinct gr2 as prop, count(distinct us ) as users
limit 10
```

any better?

Comment: yes! worked like a charm. It is just like using the 1.9 "START", it makes the new cypher 2.0 looks a little bit incompetent ...

Comment: Oh great :-) Same concept really- the number of paths that would have matched the entire pattern gr<-us->gr2 was very large as your profile indicated. Just broke it up to restrict by the gr you wanted to filter on.